# Why does `ls` list the following files in seemingly different orders?

Tags: ls, sort, locale

Why does `ls` list the following files in seemingly different orders?

By default, doesn't `ls` list files in the lexicographical order for my current locale, which I guess is the default one?

```
$ ls
a_1  a_10  a_11  a_12

$ ls
a_10-18  a_11-18  a_1-18  a_12-18
```

I have `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` and `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"`.

Comment: `ls -v` would sort your files in the second example as `a_1-18  a_10-18  a_11-18   a_12-18`.

Comment: For the question whose answer led to this one, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327508/

Answer (score 8):

**Locale is really complicated.** The aim is to get something that "feels normal" to non-technical users. (Technical folks can use `LANG=C` to get that warm fuzzy feeling.) The technical definition is a [Unicode standard document](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/), and I've attempted to distill some of that here. Corrections happily received.

I find it interesting to read that *locale* is a property of the user handling the data, not of the data itself. The technical document goes to some lengths to clarify this with reference to sorting order for a German user being different to that of a Swedish user even though the characters used in the example strings are the same.

The en_GB and en_US locales are set up to ignore the `-` character. Very much simplified, these locales' sorting rules for ascending order are:

1. Case is insensitive
2. If you have two strings where they are initially the same except that one is longer, it sorts second. So `xyzA` is always after `xyz`
3. Some punctuation (in this situation including `-`) is ignored unless being compared to other punctuation
4. Digits sort before letters
5. Digits are sorted `0`..`9`
6. Letters are sorted `[Aa]`..`[Zz]` (en_GB and en_US don't really have accents)
7. For any given letter, lowercase is sorted before uppercase (so `one` comes before `One`, but both come before `two`)
8. Punctuation is sorted (but it's not relevant to the examples in this answer)

Applying these rules to the datasets in question:

> ```
> a_1  a_10  a_11  a_12
> ```

This is equivalent to `a1` `a10` `a11` `a12`, and given the rule #2 we get that `a1` must be before `a10` and `a11`. EVerything other than `a1` has the same number of alphanumeric characters so they can be compared consistently. This gives us `a_1` `a_10` `a_11` `a_12`.

> ```
> a_10-18  a_11-18  a_1-18  a_12-18
> ```

The same rules apply, except that #3 also applies (we ignore punctuation). This means we can consider the values as `a_1018` `a_1118` `a_118` `a_1218`, and following the rules #2 and #4 we get the order `a_10-18` `a_11-18` `a_1-18` `a_12-18`.

Taking our final example from the comments

> ```
> a_10 a_10- a_100 a_101 a_10-18 a_102
> ```

Rules #3, and then #2, #4 apply. So we remove (ignore) the `-` characters giving us `a_10` `a_10` `a_100` `a_101` `a_1018` `a_102`, and sort the remainder by common substring prefix and then by order of characters.

(It's not clear to me whether we get `a_10` and then `a_10-` by virtue of the length, or just because it happens to end up that way. I'm tempted to suggest the latter, but I'd love someone to confirm this.)

Answer (score 1):

In lexicographic order, `a_1` comes before any other string starting with `a_1`. Since the digits are in numerical order in any reasonable locale, it follows that in any reasonable locale, `a_1` < `a_10` < `a_11` < `a_12`.

If you add a common suffix to those strings, the order can change because that common suffix might be sorted somewhere in the middle. In your second example, there are four strings starting with the common prefix `a_1`, and with the respective suffixes `0-18`, `1-18`, `-18` and `2-18`. In the C locale, strings are compared on a strict lexicographic basis; `-` comes before digits, so `-18` comes first: `a_10-18` < `a_11-18` < `a_1-18` < `a_12-18`. But most other locales are more complicated. In particular, punctuation is ignored except as a last resort. So to compare the strings 
`a_10-18` < `a_11-18` < `a_1-18` < `a_12-18`, you first compare the punctuationless strings `a1018`, `a1118` `a118` `a1218`; the order for the second digit is `0` < `1` < `1` < `2`, and for the middle two strings the order for the third digit is `1` < `8`. If you add a string that differs only in punctuation, then the differing punctuation will determine how it's sorted, e.g. `a_10-18` < `a_1-118` < `a_11-18` < `a_12-18`

The explanation in my answer is simplified. There can be more than two passes, to cope with things like punctuation. The [ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/concepts) has a fairly detailed explanation (but even that doesn't handle all the subtleties that go into sorting things like book indexes).

Comment: `-` doesn't necessarily come before digits. In some locales it's ignored unless being compared to other punctuation. See `a10  a10-  a1-0  a-10  a20  a20-  a2-0  a-20` where you get `a10 a10-` ("longer") but `a1-0 a-10` (same length and apparently `-` is before `1`) and `a2-0  a-20` (same length but apparently now `2` is before `-`).