# How can I get and set the locale used by `ls`?

Tags: ls, locale

When run in bash, `ls` by default sort output files by a lexicographical order wrt the current locale.

Is the locale a property belonging to bash, `ls`, or my OS Ubuntu?

How can I get and set the locale?

Comment: This is a follow-on question from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328185/ , and part of a series exploring `ls` and its sorting behaviour.

Comment: You feel like my mind reader

Answer (score 3):

Locales are supported by operating system (or better by `libc`). You can set your locales as variable environment (for your terminal program) or in your desktop environment/manager (for graphical programs), so that operation system know what locale you want (see `LANG` and `LC_...` variables).

But at the end, it is `ls` which ask operation system about the preferred locale and do what it is appropriate.

Note: `ls` has also an option not to sort files.

So if you write `LANG=C ls` or `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ls` to force an other locale.

Comment: And if you only want to affect the sorting and not other localisation aspects (like time format for `ls -l` or the character set (for `ls` to know which character it can display properly)), you can set `LC_COLLATE` only: `LC_COLLATE=C ls -l`