# What are the definition of a prefix, version number and suffix in a filename for version sorting?

Tags: ls, sort, coreutils

In the manual for coreutils,

> **10.1.4 Details about version sort**,
>
> Version sorting handles the fact that file names frequently include
>   **indices or version numbers**. Standard sorting usually does not produce
>   the order that one expects because comparisons are made on a
>   character-by-character basis. Version sorting is especially useful
>   when browsing directories that contain many fi les with
>   indices/version numbers in their names:
>
> ```
> $ ls -1       $ ls -1v
> abc.zml-1.gz  abc.zml-1.gz
> abc.zml-12.gz abc.zml-2.gz
> abc.zml-2.gz  abc.zml-12.gz
> ```
>
> Version-sorted strings are compared such that if `ver1` and `ver2` are
>   **version numbers** and **prefix** and **suffix** (suffix matching the regular
>   expression `‘(\.[A-Za-z~][A-Za-z0-9~]*)*’`) are strings then `ver1` < `ver2`
>   implies that the name composed of `prefix ver1 suffix` sorts before
>   `prefix ver2 suffix`.
>
> Note also that leading zeros of numeric parts are ignored:
>
> ```
> $ ls -1        $ ls -1v
> abc-1.007.tgz  abc-1.01a.tgz
> abc-1.012b.tgz abc-1.007.tgz
> abc-1.01a.tgz  abc-1.012b.tgz
> ```
>
> This functionality is implemented using gnulib’s `filevercmp`
>   function, which has some caveats worth noting.
>
> • `LC_COLLATE` is ignored, which means `ls -v` and `sort -V` will sort
>   non-numeric **prefixes** as if the `LC_COLLATE` locale category was set to
>   `C`.
>
> • Some **suffixes** will not be matched by the regular expression
>   mentioned above. Consequently these examples may not sort as you
>   expect:
>
> ```
> abc-1.2.3.4.7z
> abc-1.2.3.7z
> abc-1.2.3.4.x86_64.rpm
> abc-1.2.3.x86_64.rpm
> ```

1. Given a filename, what are the definitions of a prefix, version
   number, and suffix?
2. For a suffix, in the regular expression
   `‘(\.[A-Za-z~][A-Za-z0-9~]*)*’`,

   - what does `~` mean?
   - is `‘` part of the regular expression?

   Is the syntax of regular expressions introduced somewhere?
3. In the three examples, what are the prefixes, version numbers and
   suffixes of the filenames?
4. In the last example, the one in the last caveat, why are the filenames sorted that way by version sorting?

Thanks.

Comment: This is part of a series exploring the sort behavior of `ls` and follows from the commentary at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328185/ .

Answer (score 2):

Granted, it's poorly explained.

Ultimate edification can only be achieved by reading the source code: https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/filevercmp.c. Basically:

The suffix is the longest string matching `(\.[A-Za-z~][A-Za-z0-9~]*)*$`. Note the `$` which requires the match to be at the end of the filename. Dot-separated parts of the suffix are treated as version numbers for comparison purposes.

The `~` is just a character that may appear in a filename. This is sometimes used in version numbers like `3.4.1~alpha`.

> In the last example, the one in the last caveat, why are the filenames sorted that way by version sorting?

Because `_` is not an allowed suffix character, the files that end in `x86_64.rpm` are treated as versionless (or just `rpm` considered as a version). It's not clear why they aren't sorted in dictionary order as a fallback though.

Comment: Thanks. What are the definitions of a prefix and a version number in a filename?  In the filenames appearing in the three examples, what are their prefixes, version numbers, and suffixes?